# Is it possible to detect the type of WiFi you're connecting to?

Tags: java, android

I want to detect if the WiFi that I am connecting to is a actual wifi or a wifi from a tethered hotspot from another mobile device - a hotspot that is actually a mobile data connection.

Is it possible to do that via the native android API? I've seen a few apps successfully detect that and warn me of actions that I am about to do.

Comment: I guess you can retrieve it by `conectionInfo.getBSSID();` how ever you can create a work around solution, get the network class and check if it is common in android devices or not 
this solution works if and only if they are threating the hotspot from their devices, all android devices should have the same class since you can't change DHCP in android unless if the phone is rooted

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Connectivity {

/**
 * Get the network info
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
}

/**
 * Check if there is any connectivity
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected());
}

/**
 * Check if there is any connectivity to a Wifi network
 * @param context
 * @param type
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
}

/**
 * Check if there is any connectivity to a mobile network
 * @param context
 * @param type
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
}

/**
 * Check if there is fast connectivity
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isConnectedFast(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected() && Connectivity.isConnectionFast(info.getType(),info.getSubtype()));
}

/**
 * Check if the connection is fast
 * @param type
 * @param subType
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isConnectionFast(int type, int subType){
    if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
        return true;
    }else if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
        switch(subType){
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
            return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
            return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
            return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
            return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
            return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
            return false; // ~ 100 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
            return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
            return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
            return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
            return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
        /*
         * Above API level 7, make sure to set android:targetSdkVersion 
         * to appropriate level to use these
         */
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD: // API level 11 
            return true; // ~ 1-2 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: // API level 9
            return true; // ~ 5 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP: // API level 13
            return true; // ~ 10-20 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: // API level 8
            return false; // ~25 kbps 
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE: // API level 11
            return true; // ~ 10+ Mbps
        // Unknown
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}